# How to send an email to multiple recipients with different text in the body

Tags: .net, email

I am sending out an email that has multiple people in the To: field.  Some of those users are internal to my company and others are external. For the internal people I want to add some additional text to the email that I don't want the external people to see. I cannot split this into two emails because the internal people want to see the external people in the To: field.

Is this possible?

Comment: add the names / emails of the external people in the email body

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No this is not inherently possible (I say Inherently because there may very well be a library that facilitates this type of functionality) you will need to send two separate emails.

You may think about adding the external recipients to the body of the email that is sent to the internal recipients.